# Помогите с ботом для вк

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

```
request.urlretrieve(update['object']['attachments'][0]['photo']['photo_2560'], "1.jpg")
api.messages.markAsRead(peer_id = update['object']['user_id'])
image = cv2.imread("1.jpg")
image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cv2.imwrite("2.jpg",image)
image1 = cv2.imread("2.jpg")
api.messages.send(user_id = update['object']['user_id'], random_id = randint(-2147483648, 2147483647), message = 'Обработанное фото',attachments = image1)
```

Как прикрепить сообщение? attachments не работает(может помочь https://github.com/bixnel/vkpython/blob/master/bot.py)

Comment: Для начала его надо загрузить через VK Upload Server, после загрузки сервер вернёт вам строку-идентификатор приложения, которую и надо отправлять.

Comment: Можно код я хз как это делать